# Find Where .Net Assembly Is Being Pulled From

Tags: .net, assemblies

I have fou.dll that also needs friendfou.dll
When I compile my project friendfoul.dll is being pulled into my bin folder from somewhere, I can tell because I delete friendfoul.dll and it reappears on compile.

How can I tell where friendfoul.dll is being pulled from?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the project file (*project_name*.csproj for a C# project, for instance) and look for the  entry with the  entries, you can find the info you seek there, I believe.

Comment: yea, only for fou.dll though not friendfou.dll

Answer (score 0):

Open the Solution Explorer, expand the project's References node and open the Properties window of the fou.dll reference. You will see the path from where it is being copied.

Comment: true, but friendfoul.dll isn't there

Comment: In fact friendfoul.dll is in many places. I inherited a massive solution where friendfoul.dll needs to be located in many, many, many places.

Comment: and to top it off they all have the same version number but different build dates and file sizes and I'm trying to clean this krap up

Comment: so it's not added as a reference but still being copied there?

Comment: correct, my project never references firendfou.dll but it is a reference in fou.dll

Comment: maybe this related question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325745/order-of-assembly-resolution-during-compile

Answer (score 0):

Since you said in comments that friendfou.dll is not a reference of your project, try looking at a build events if dll is copied from somewhere. To find build events, go to project properties, on build events tab and look at pre-build or post-build event command lines and see if there are any references to friendfou.dll